# IPython notebook CSS formatting messed up

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

For some reason my IPython notebook looks like this:

[image]

There is no formatting, and the text is sometimes laid on top of each other. I tried it in Chrome and Firefox. I'm running Windows 8, with IPython installed through Anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a wrong MIME type for CSS files in the Windows Registry.

Try reset the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.css` key (after backing it up):

```
REGEDIT4

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.css]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.css]
@="CSSfile"
"PerceivedType"="text"
"Content Type"="text/css"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.css\PersistentHandler]
@="{eec97550-47a9-11cf-b952-00aa0051fe20}"
```